# How to pass additional parameters (as a dict) to sagemeker custom inference container?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Status:

- Custom container is built using the doc - https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own
- predict.py is coded to accommodate the custom inference script and its working well
- Using the classsagemaker.model.Model() class to pass the trained model.tar.gz and custom container image inorder to deploy the model

Challenge:

- In the same Model class there is a ENV  parameter through which we can apparently send the environment variables to the custom image
- Tried passing a python dict to this , but facing difficulty to read this json dict inide the predict.py script

Somebody faced the same difficulty ?

Comment: why do you need a dict? how about creating a different environment variable for each parameter?

Comment: @OlivierCruchant Thanks for the reply , i have tried that out too. Like this :
 `env = {'var1': '1'}`
The issue is that I cannot see this variable inside the env, nor I can read it. may be I am missing something here!

Comment: no I meant why not env={'var1': 'value1', ..., 'varN': 'valueN'}

Comment: @OlivierCruchant ,  i have no difficulties with the passing of the dict, i am struggling to read this env inside the inference container.

Comment: os.environ['var1'] ?

Comment: eg in your model_fn

Comment: @OlivierCruchant , Hi thanks for the inputs , i got it working in sagemaker studio! may be some libraries in notebook instance didn't support this. I'm gonna find that out now! But super happy that it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your environment dict in your Model as:

```
Model(
.
.
env= {"my_env": "my_env_value"}
.
.
)
```

SageMaker will pass the enviroments dict to your container and you can access it in your predict.py script for example with:

```
my_env = os.environ.get('my_env',"env key not set in Model")
print(my_env)
```

If your env dict was passed to your Model containing they `my_env` then you will receive the output : `my_env_value`. Else, then you will receive `env key not set in Model`

I work for AWS and my opinions are my own.